# Pixi JS and background gradients

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, pixi.js

I am trying to add a background to the canvas but cannot seem to do so.

```
// create a renderer instance
var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(W, H);

// add the renderer view element to the DOM
document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);
var canvas = renderer.view; // This returns the canvas DOM element
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
console.log (ctx); //This returns null
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: So you're wondering why on earth isn't a webGL renderer using a Context2D by default to render. Hum.

Comment: Oops, I specified it to use canvas and it worked. Thanks haha, completely overlooked that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, while the comments above have the answer in them, I figured I should highlight the answer.

Using the autoDetectRenderer returned the WebGLRenderer.  Explicitly setting the renderer to CanvasRenderer provides access to the context object.